# Always use use cases or not?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture, use-case

I've been wondering a little about use cases in my latest project. It seems like there are many use cases with only one line of code just forwarding the message to a repository.

Now as I understand the use cases should contain business logic only just forwarding a message has nothing to do with business logic most of the time. It feels like creating a use case for every action is a bit overkill. And I'm starting to lean towards direct communication to a repository unless the use case would add value like for example the `RegisterUserUseCase` which does multiple calls to different repositories.

How do you guys feel about this? Which approach do you follow? And why do you do so?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

The task of a use case is to:

- validate the request model (in meaning of business rules)
- query or persist entities with repositories
- implement the application specific domain logic.

A use case is also often the transaction boundary or other aspects are handled at the use case level.

There are some use cases that do not a lot of business logic or even none, like  a data export use case. Those use cases should be rare, but even those use cases usually validate the request model. I would prefer to keep the architecture even in those rare use cases to be consistent.

If you have a lot of use cases that do not contain any business logic, your business logic is probably spread accross the controller and/or repository or application specific logic moved to the entities which should only contain application agnostic business logic.